# HTML column below minimum width in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

On a downloads overview page for a [download manager](http://www.wpdownloadmanager.com/) plugin for Wordpress there are multiple columns and the shortcode column overlaps the author column. I've set that column's minimum width to 175px but when the window is resized still shrinks below it's minimum width.

```
.column-wpdmshortcode{
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
    border-bottom-color: rgb(225, 225, 225);
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    color: rgb(50, 55, 60);
    display: table-cell;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 19.6000003814697px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 77px;
    word-wrap: break-word;

    min-width: 175px;
}
```

All inherited css properties:
http://spencerlarry.com/docs/all-inherited-styles.txt

[image]

I'm wondering how it's possible to have an element like this be below it's `min-width`. 
 Any ideas how I could fix this problem?

Comment: Spencer, Hard to check without seeing the full code.

Comment: How much padding you have here? Do use border-box property?

Comment: Spencer, can you show us your full code?

Comment: Nope. Create a http://jsfiddle.net with the generated HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`min-width` and `max-width` are not supported on table cells.

From the [CSS2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-widths):

> In CSS 2.1, the effect of 'min-width' and 'max-width' on tables,
>   inline tables, table cells, table columns, and column groups is
>   undefined.

So one thing you should do is to set the `width` of the cell (and not the `min-width`), and use the [`table-layout`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp) property to `fixed` so the cells widths will no be longer auto calculated.